# Finder Instantly Crashing

Tags: finder, crash

Finder crashes as soon as I open it, In addition to this, when I plugged my iPod into my Mac, that started crashing too and now doesn't boot.

Crash logs:
http://pastebin.com/TCa9CaC3

Comment: So if you disconnect all cables from your Mac except for perhaps a keyboard, mouse and display if needed. What happens if you reboot the Mac into Safe Mode? Then if you shut down cleanly and restart normally - again without anything optional connected?

Comment: It now doesn't boot.

Comment: Not booting again trumps any crash from the system before it went down. You'll want to edit in the specific hardware and OS or contact Apple Support for guidance in what details are needed to start making recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

Rebooting fixes the finder crash. The iOS crash must be a separate issue

Comment: There is nothing here I see that adds to the question. Apart from if they want to know the reason the Mac was crashing. The iOs crash should be a new question.  @hooj you should accept the answer if you feel your problem is solved and pose a new question for the iOS device if you want help. If not then you should do as Graham suggests.